# Can notion of submodularity be extended to functions that are not proper?

Tags: functions

I am familiar with notion of submodularity in functions whose range is $\mathbb{R}$. I was wondering if the notion extends to functions whose range is $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$.